# Hibernate and generics

Tags: hibernate, generics

In Java I have a class tha has a payload of type T

```
public class GenericStatus<T> {
   private MyDateRange myDateRange;  
   private T payload;
```

At runtime T can be either a simple primitive Integer or a class called Price where Price is a class with 2 integers

```
public class Price implements Serializable {
   private int adult;
   private int child;
```

How can you deal with loading / saving of the class GenericStatusElement ? I have 2 classes that are using this

```
public class MasterPrice implements Serializable {
    // this.basePrice is an instance of Price class
    private GenericStaus prices = new GenericStatus(this.basePrice);
```

and

```
public class MasterStatus implements Serializable {
    // roomcount is an int
    GenericStaus availStatus = new GenericStatus(roomCount);
```

I keep scratching my head but I still cannot find a proper way to deal with GenericStatus from Hibernate point of view.

I would like to be able to save the MasterPrice and MasterStatus classes. GenericStatus class is used to reduce the duplicate code that MasterStatus and MasterPrice would have. Shall I look to implement the relationship with inheritance ? will it make easier to fix ?

Comment: this is a really good question.

Comment: How are you expecting this to be represented in a database?

Comment: @Damo. MasterStatus should use a single int column for the roomCount (Integer). MasterPrice uses 2 int columns [adult and child which are both integers]. Therefore there should be a way to discern on runtime on what and where to map... tricky enough for me...

Comment: I think you're over complicating it. Hibernate is best used to represent what's in your database, not to impose some artificial object model on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I keep scratching my head but I still cannot find a proper way to deal with GenericStatus from Hibernate point of view.

The answer is simple: generic entities can not be mapped.

> Shall I look to implement the relationship with inheritance ? will it make easier to fix ?

That's what I'd do.